# How to implementing Razorpay Test Mode Withdrawal in Django Web App

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I'm in the process of developing a Django web app where users can initiate withdrawals with the following flow:

1. On the website, users have the option to withdraw a specific amount.
2. Upon clicking the withdraw button, users are directed to the next page.
3. On this page, users are prompted to enter their bank details.
4. After saving the bank details, users can click the "Continue" button.
5. At this point, I want the specified amount to be automatically transferred to the entered bank account, all while operating in Razorpay's test mode.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, code examples, or references on how to implement this flow effectively. Your help is invaluable.

Thank you!